# How to get data from HTTP json in Angular

Tags: json, angular, http, rest

kindly help
I am trying to get Json data from HTTP link

```
<span class="subjectSpan">{{ title }}</span>
```

and the .ts file conatins

```
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private api:ServiceUserService) {};
  title:any;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.title = this.api.apiCall().subscribe(data => {
      this.title = data;
    })
  }
```

and the .service.ts file has

```
apiCall() {
    return this.httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  }
```

I have imported HTTPCLIENTMODULE in module.ts and .ts file

Just the data from json is not showing just

`[object object]` is coming as result.

the json file contains

```
{"status":"success","results":2,"data":{"subject":[{"subject":"ART & HUMANITIES","numTitles":1,"slug":"art-humanities"},{"subject":"ANTHROPOLOGY","numTitles":1,"slug":"anthropology"}]}}
```

or getting this error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"title"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
  Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Comment: You shouldn't assign this.title twice, you only need it inside the subscriber function. Remove the first `this.title = ..."`

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned before it shows [Object object] because you are sending whole object.

If you want to see it works correctly change

`<span class="subjectSpan">{{ title }}</span>`

to

`<span class="subjectSpan">{{ title | json }}</span>`

If you want to get just one of the properties of the object then I would suggest to create `interface` for the object.

This way you can type variable `title` to correct object (having specified properties) and in template you can get whatever you want by for example `{{title.success}}`

Also I would suggest you to type the return value of the function.
Change this

```
apiCall() {
return this.httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
```

}

to

```
apiCall(): Observable<**interface you have created**>{
    return this.httpClient.get<**interface you have created**>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  }
```

EDIT: It would be nice to assign data to variable only when they exist so in this case add condition in your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing [Object object] in title because you are passing the whole json object to the title variable declared in the component, whereas you should be specifying the key in the received json Object.
For example : In your json response you have "subject":"ART & HUMANITIES"
json -> data -> subject -> 0th index -> subject

Therefore you might want to change the line
this.title = data;
to
this.title = data['data']['subject'][0]['subject'];

also
this.api.apiCall().subscribe(...) wont return title so remove that assignment.

Comment: When I do this its shows ERROR:
``` Cannot find name 'data'.

55     this.title = data['data']['subject'][0]['subject'];
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ todos ? todos.id : "" }}

todos exist data then display data.

**`Typescript`**
public todos : any;

value assign public varchar

todos = res;